# Can I use "still" in place of "yet" in these contexts?

Tags: grammar

Context: I want to be single and "yet" attached. I want to be alone "yet" accompanied.

I have read that yet is used in the last of the sentence like he has not given yet, etc.
In these yet is not used in the last but in the middle, so, can I use still in place of yet so that meaning remains same?

Comment: Using ***yet*** in your context is a bit dated/formal - most people usually use ***but*** today. You can include ***still*** with either conjunction to emphasise the "quirkiness" of wanting both A ***and*** B, which superficially appear to be mutually exclusive alternatives: *I want to be alone **but still** [feel?] accompanied*.

Comment: Can I write this "I want to be alone but accompanied" without using still?

Comment: Yes, you can, if you want your statement to look slightly more paradoxical at first glance.

Comment: Indeed. "but", "still", "(and) yet" are all more or less equivalent ways of showing the contrast, perhaps with a different degree of drawing attention to the contrast. None of them is dated (in this context, anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the intent of your examples is to show contrast

> single **yet** attached
>   alone **yet** accompanied

and "**still**" can be used to show this contrast also, however "**still**" implies a *continuation* of state, so logically it would be

> attached **yet still** single
>   accompanied **yet still** alone

since in both cases the *assumed* initial sites would be "**single**" and "**alone**", and as has been pointed out in the *comments*, your use of "**yet**" is similar to "**but**"

> attached **but** *(still)* single
>   accompanied **but** *(still)* alone

both work, however

> attached **still** single
>   accompanied **still** alone

do not.  So, no, you cannot simply replace "**yet**" with "**still**".